Configure an interpreter using WSL with VS Code
Within VS Code, I would like to configure a conda environment living in WSL as the interpreter of a project living in Windows. This is possible with PyCharm, as indicated here.
With VS Code, I can successfully connect to WSL with the Remote Explorer extension and select a conda environment living in WSL, as indicated here, but it seems I can only use it for projects living in WSL, not for projects living in Windows.
Is there a way to use a conda environment living in WSL for projects living in Windows, within VS Code?

For a scenario like this, I typically build a docker image and choose "reopen in container".

I have Windows in local and wls2.
I installed conda for wsl and I have runned a project of local.
First, find the path of the local project u wanna open in wsl.
For example C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\try. Then u can open a linux terminal and do wslpath "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\try", to convert the path to linux path. The files of the local are situated in /mnt folder. /mnt/c/Users/user_name/Desktop/try/.
Then u can just do code /mnt/c/Users/user_name/Desktop/try/ to open it.
But wsl recommends store the project in /home to have a better performance. I recommend to push the project to GitHub and then clone it using wsl vscode.
I understand that u can not use local conda env in wsl, so u must use wsl conda (linux conda).
Example
